# Expositions of the classical approach to local class field theory (Brauer group and Hasse invariant)

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I've posted this question already [on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4806817/428713) and didn't get much out of it, so I hope it's OK to repost here.

I'm an undergraduate trying to learn local class field theory from the corresponding chapter of [Lorenz's "Algebra 2"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-72488-1), which, according to its mission statement, takes a more classical approach

> [Local class field theory] admits of a remarkably simple demonstration based on the algebra-theoretic results of the previous chapter [Brauer groups, crossed products, and the Hasse invariant]. This proof, though very satisfying in several regards and dating back to H. Hasse and E. Noether, is apparently lesser known than it deserves to be.

The chapter in question is excellent, but a little tough, so I was hoping to find some **supplemental sources** (Lorenz doesn't list any). One such text I've found is Guillot's "A Gentle Introduction to Local Class Field Theory", however while it's very similar in the beginning, it goes off in a different direction in the chapters on CFT proper, concentrating more on Galois cohomology, while Lorenz takes a more elementary algebra-theoretic approach. Since Lorenz mentions Hasse and Noether, I would like to mention that I speak German, so sources from either that happen to be available only in the original language would not be a problem (although I'm looking for more modern sources).

To clarify, I already know the basics of CSAs, the Brauer group, crossed products/cyclic algebras, and the Hasse invariant, what I'm looking for is a source that applies this theory to local CFT.

Comment: Maybe Hazewinkel's [Local class field theory is easy](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/9964/9964D.pdf) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ina Kersten's book on Brauergruppen is available online and offers a highly readable introduction.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I had Hazewinkel's article suggested to me on MSE. Having skimmed it a little, it doesn't seem to use the Brauer group and the Hasse invariant, which is the kind of exposition I'm looking for.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer I'm already familiar with the theory of the Brauer group itself (having used Kersten at one point), what I'm looking for is an exposition of local CFT that uses this theory to derive its results. Kersten's book doesn't cover this.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Section 7 of my [History of class-field theory](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/cfthistory.pdf) would be helpful. See references [[3](https://doi.org/10.2969/aspm/03010031)] and [[18](https://doi.org/10.1007/b138384)] there.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, what you describe on pg.22 about the determination of the Artin symbol is what I'm looking for essentially (greatly expanded, however)

You write on the next page "...developments in class field theory led to a stripping away of the algebras (which after all were defined entirely in terms of the number fields themselves) in proofs of class field theory, leaving behind only cohomological formalism", so I wanted to ask whether there's any reason for me to not pursue this line of exposition (since it's apparently outdated) and just go for group cohomology stuff

Comment: I think it is worth seeing how this stuff used to be worked out (maybe not as far as reading all the proofs, if you are pressed for time), since it can help you better appreciate what all the abstract formalism is saying in a more concrete way.  It is comparable to seeing how Artin reciprocity implies concrete power reciprocity laws, which preceded Artin reciprocity historically and is the reason for the continued use of the name "reciprocity" when there is no more sign of actual reciprocity anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

For an overview of the algebraic approach to local class field theory, I highly recommend Chapter 8 of [*Number Theory 2: Introduction to Class Field Theory*](https://www.ams.org/books/mmono/240/) by Kazuya Kato, Nobushige Kurokawa, and Takeshi Saito.

For further details, you can refer to Chapters 3 and 4 in the relatively new textbook [*Class Field Theory and L Functions: Foundations and Main Results*](https://www.routledge.com/Class-Field-Theory-and-L-Functions-Foundations-and-Main-Results/Halter-Koch/p/book/9781138583580) by Franz Halter-Koch. Halter-Koch has admirably filled almost all the gaps in Lorenz's book, making it possibly the only comprehensive option. Unfortunately, other English references to this purely algebraic approach, such as Weil's [*Basic Number Theory*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61945-8), are somewhat sketchy.

For German readers, a classic reference is [*Algebren*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-85533-7) by Max Deuring, but it might be considered somewhat outdated.

Comment: I'll check out the first book, thanks. I was actually already familiar with Halter-Koch and he even lists Lorenz as one of his primary references, so the exposition is very similar, but I find him extremely taxing to read due to the ultra-dense way the pages are typeset. I'll try coming back to him again at some point, but at the moment whenever I open the book I just go cross-eyed.